# How to access bake margin from python?

Tags: python, image, texture-baking

[image: image bake settings]

I'm building a color ID baker and I'd like to access the margin slider on my addon. I've looked in the API and gone through numerous attempts, but I can't quite figure out the python command to change it, much less implement it elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bake settings are a collection of settings available in `bpy.context.scene.render.bake`.

So, to access the *Margin* you would do:

```
bpy.context.scene.render.bake.margin = 16
```

This was a little tricky to find, but there were a few hints.

1. Hovering over the *Margin* property showed the tooltip, which revealed that the bake options were going to be in the *Scene*'s properties.
2. Baking is linked to rendering, which made me think to look under the `bpy.context.scene.render` settings.

The best way to explore the Api is via blender's *Python Console* editor and use *Autocomplete* to see the available properties of a given class, e.g. typing `bpy.context.scene.` and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> will reveal:

```
>>> bpy.context.scene.
                      NWBusyDrawing
                      NWLazySource
                      NWLazyTarget
                      NWSourceSocket
                      active_clip
                      active_layer
                      alembic_export(
                      animation_data
                      animation_data_clear(
                      animation_data_create(
                      appended_header
                      as_pointer(
                      audio_distance_model
                      audio_doppler_factor
                      audio_doppler_speed
                      audio_volume
                      etc......
                      etc....
                      etc..
```

Comment: Epic! Thank you Ray :) It sucks being a noob.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem and tried Ray's above method, but no matter which parameters I supplied, i.e. 8 px vs 16 px, the resulting UV map showed no difference.

After a lot of tinkering I found that the proper line to access the Margin property is:

```
bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.bake_margin = 8
```

Comment: My answer still works for me. All that using `bpy.data.scenes["Scene"]` does instead of `bpy.context.scene` is that it uses a specific scene ('Scene'), instead of the current one.